# CUDA: cannot use tex2D in the header file

Tags: c++, cuda

I tried to define an inline function in a .cuh file:

```cpp
inline __device__ glm::vec3 getAlbedo(const glm::vec2& uv, const Texture& tex) {
    float4 baseTex = tex2D<float4>(tex.devTexture, uv.x, uv.y);
    return glm::vec3{ baseTex.x, baseTex.y, baseTex.z };
}
```

However I got a compile error stating "tex2D: undefined identifier.". I called this inline function in a `__global__` function, where I used to explicitly call `tex2D`.

Comment: you haven't shown the definition of `Tex.devTexture`.  The thing you are passing is `tex`.  But if you are including this .cuh file in a .cpp file anywhere, that generally won't work.  You can't compile textures like this (or a `__device__` function, for that matter) using a host code compiler.  Anyway, you should provide a short, complete example, so we don't have to play 20 questions.  I also note that you have not asked a question here.

Comment: @robert-crovella Hi. tex.devTexture is a cudaTextureObject_t. All my files are either .cuh or .cu., and the item types are CUDA C/C++.

Comment: @robert-crovella `tex` is a struct. I assume I have to directly pass the `cudaTextureObject_t` instead of a struct wrapping it?

Comment: sure, but the struct `tex` is named with a lower-case `t`.  The thing you pass to the texture op starts with an upper case `T`: `Tex.devTexture`.   So this obviously isn't the code you are trying to compile.  Again, a short complete example, please, or not, as you choose.  I don't intend to respond to any further comments.

Comment: I don't seem to have any trouble with [this](https://pastebin.com/NmWsnZTg)

Comment: @robert-crovella Thanks for your update. I replaced `inline` with `__inline__` and the compilation succeeded this time. I guess there is a bug on my machine causing vc to process all `inline` and switch to `__inline__` forces to use nvcc.

Answer (score 1):

Replace `inline` with `__inline__` solve the problem.